# Uncaught ReferenceError: using TypeScript, RequireJS and PureMVC

Tags: requirejs, typescript, puremvc

I got this problem and I couldn't figure out why. I keep getting "ReferenceError: puremvc is not defined"

Can someone take a look?
Attached are images of my folder structure, index.html, main.ts and DataProxy.ts and its error.

Here is what my folders structure looks like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbkRt.jpg

Here is my index.html file
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wksks.jpg

Comment: Here is my main.ts file
http://i.stack.imgur.com/FPSMT.jpg

Here is my DataProxy.ts and it's error
http://i.stack.imgur.com/FXm5X.jpg

Comment: main.ts and index.html look like they are inside the js directory. Have you tried dropping `/js/` from your references or doing `../js/lib/` at the start of them. Also I am using the latest version of TypeScript and the Visual Studio Extension and latest version and I have included Knockout and JQuery .d.ts definitely typed reference files and I have no need to use RequireJS... oh wait your on a Mac nvm

Answer (score 0):

Your paths don't look quite right - it looks from your images as if the paths should be:

```
<script src="/js/lib/puremvc/puremvc-typescript-standard-1.0-min.js"></script>
```

Note the leading `/` as it makes all the difference

This makes the URI relative to the root of your site, which means this path would work wherever you placed your `index.html` in your website.

Comment: Not sure what file that I use /js/lib/, I think all the reference like this "../../lib

DataProxy.ts:
///<reference path='../../lib/puremvc/puremvc-typescript-standard-1.0.d.ts'/>

Here is the zip file:
http://vnfx.com/TestPureMVC.zip

Comment: In your `index.html` file you have the actual script tag.

Comment: if I use /js/lib/ then I can't even load the js files because the index.html is not at the root

Comment: When you start a URL with / it will be relative to the root of the site, not the document. This means it will work no matter where the document is.

Comment: if you run this on the desktop then there is no root, isn't it?

Comment: You only have a root if you run via a web server.